# JWPlayer & XML feed

Tags: xml, expressionengine, jwplayer

I use JW Player to load all my videos and Im exporting all of my blog entries to an XML feed.

JW Player loads through JS like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jwplayer('playermzsaYhpGaotY').setup({
    file: '',
    image: '',
    width: '100%',
    aspectratio: '16:9',
    ga: '{}',
    sharing: '{}'
});// ]]></script>
```

This works great for the browser but leads to an invalid XML feed. This is my current feed setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entries>
    {exp:weblog:entries weblog="default_site" show_future_entries="yes" limit="1000" rdf="off"}
      <entry>
        <title>{title}</title>
        <slug>{url_title}</slug>
        <author>{username}</author>
        <postdate>{entry_date}</postdate>
        <expirationdate>{expiration_date}</expirationdate>
        <summary><![CDATA[{summary}]]></summary>
        <text><![CDATA[{body}]]></text>
        <tags>
          {categories}
          <tag>{category_name}</tag>
          {/categories}
          {exp:tag:tags type="weblog" entry_id="{entry_id}" }
          <tag>{tag}</tag>
          {/exp:tag:tags}
        </tags>
      </entry>
     {/exp:weblog:entries}
    </entries>
```

I already wrap "{body}" in CDATA but it seems to run into an issue with this response:

Opening and ending tag mismatch: text line 0 and script

Here is a copy of the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entries>
            <entry>
                <title>Title</title>
                <slug>slug</slug>
                <author>author</author>
                <postdate>1402393823</postdate>
                <expirationdate>0</expirationdate>
                <summary><![CDATA[Summary]]></summary>
                <text>
                  <![CDATA[
                            <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
                                jwplayer('playermzsaYhpGaotY').setup({
                                file: '',
                                image: '',
                                width: '100%',
                                aspectratio: '16:9',
                                ga: '{}',
                                sharing: '{}'
                            });
                            // ]]></script>
                 <p>&nbsp;</p>
                 <p></p>
                 <p></p>
                 <p></p>
                 <p></p>]]>
                </text>
                <tags>
                  <tag></tag>
                  <tag></tag>
                  <tag></tag>
                  <tag></tag>
                  <tag></tag>
                  <tag></tag>
                  <tag></tag>
                  <tag></tag>
                  <tag></tag>
                </tags>
              </entry>
              </entries>
```

Ideas?

Comment: We probably need to see the output. Short of that, remove one thing at a time and see if you still get the error, e.g. remove summary, test; remove text, test; etc.  Also if you reduce the limit to '1' do you still get the error?

Comment: Also take a look at the XML Encode plugin.

Comment: Also, do you have a link?

Comment: Added a copy of the output

Comment: Link, not the output, please.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you have the CDATA declaration twice in the text field.

I find when validating here: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ that removing the inner CDATA declaration (the one inside the script tag) results in valid XML.